# How to Disable or Destroy Scrollfy stricly in Ipad Portrait mode

Tags: jquery-scrollify

I have written the below code on window resize vent

```
$(window).resize(function () {
var width = $(window).width();
        if( width <= 768){
            $.scrollify.destroy();
        }else{
            $.scrollify.update();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the title of the question I would do something like this:**

```
function scroll_page(){
    if(window.innerWidth<1260){
        if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
           $.scrollify.destroy();
        }
    }
    else{
        $(function() {
             $.scrollify({
               section : "section"
             });
         });
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    scroll_page();
});
```